# Line break no working on theme

Tags: themes, editor, line-breaks

I am working on an e-commerce site and the line breaks wont work, neither using the return button nor using `<br />` . I have been looking around but haven't found a solution that works. I would need to let the user simply push the return button and have a line break as he won't be experienced. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: _Where_ do they not work? _How_ and _where_ did you add your efforts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add line breaks using `&nbsp;` in the "Text" view like so:

https://cloudup.com/cb5PCT2sWRP

One thing to be aware of is that once you add the HTML for non-breaking spaces, you must remain in the "Text" view for future edits; switching back and forth to the visual editor will remove the above code.